# Python 3 urllib with self-signed certificates

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, urllib, self-signed

I'm attempting to download some data from an internal server using Python. Since it's internal, it uses a self-signed certificate. (We don't want to pay Verisign for servers that will never appear "in the wild.") The Python 2.6 version of the code worked fine.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
data = csv.reader(response)
```

I'm now trying to update to Python 3.4 (long story, don't ask.) However, using Python 3's urllib fails:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
```

It throws a CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error.

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)>
```

In reading around the web, apparently Python 2.6 urllib2 doesn't bother to verify certificates. Some versions of urllib allow "verify=False" to be passed to the method signature, but that doesn't appear to work in Python 3.4.

Does anyone know how I can get around this? I'd like to avoid using the Requests package because of corporate security guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urllib.request.urlopen` has a context keyword parameter that accepts an [SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) object. So, passing a `SSLContext` object with [.verify_mode](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode) set to [ssl.CERT_NONE](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ssl.html#ssl.CERT_NONE) i.e. `SSLContext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE` should be equal to `verify=False`

Answer (score 21):

Use following for disabling SSL certificate validation for a URL

```
import ssl
myssl = ssl.create_default_context();
myssl.check_hostname=False
myssl.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
urlopen("URL",context=myssl)
```

Use following to disable SSL certificate validations for all URLs

```
 ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
 urlopen("URL");
```

Answer (score 6):

As this answer still pops out first when I google for 'CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error', I would like to provide an Update:
Fully turning off SSL verification is not a good practice in general (I'll give a reason below).
It is better to add the self-signed certificate to the locally trusted certificates than to deactivate the verification completely:

```
import ssl
# add self_signed cert
myssl = ssl.create_default_context()
myssl.load_verify_locations('my_server_cert.pem')
# send request
response = urllib.request.urlopen("URL",context=myssl)
```

### Why should we care about certificate validation?

NIST and other cyber-security organizations recommend the **zero-trust model**. In short, that means: just because your server is only in the local network, it is not protected. You should take a minimum effort to secure everything in the local network.

So if you have a web server with SSL and the security certificates are not validated by the client, any attacker could still impersonate this web server or steal information by starting a man-in-the-middle attack.

You already have the private SSL certificate, so why not add it on client side and enjoy the full protection of SSL?

Answer (score 0):

With [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) :

```
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

http.request('GET', 'https://example.org')
```