# Python3's urllib to verify a self signed cert

Tags: python, ssl, urllib, self-signed

I wish to make a verified request (using Python 3.5's urllib) to a URL that is using my self-signed certificate.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError

# <version 1>
ssl_ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile="/path/to/cert.pem", keyfile="/path/to/cert.key")
# </version 1>

try:
    urlopen("https://localhost/", context=ssl_ctx)
except URLError as e:
    print(e)
```

This prints:

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)>
```

- I checked the value of `ssl_ctx.get_ca_certs()` -> `[]`
- I also check the value of `ssl_ctx.cert_store_stats()` -> `{'x509_ca': 0, 'crl': 0, 'x509': 0}`

As pointed by an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35876782) given for [Python 3 urllib with self-signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35875298), I can work around this with:

```
# <version 2>
ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_ctx.check_hostname = False
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
# </version 2>
```

But is there a way to actually verify my cert?

Comment: What specifically do you want to verify?

Comment: @oliver-charlesworth, I want to verify that the ssl cert I get is indeed *my* self singed cert, or put an ither way, given I trust my self singed key, my ssl session should be valid, and hence there are no man in the middle shananigens here.

Comment: I believe this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961564/515368