# SSL Problem with Installing `ngrok` through `pyngrok`

Tags: python, pyngrok

```
from pyngrok import ngrok
public_url = ngrok.connect(5000).public_url
```

I've taken this 2 lines of code from the twilio's documentation for automating ngrok connection.
Basically I'm just trying to establish a connection and take the web url to be then used as a webhook. but my logs keeps giving me this error:

```
Downloading ngrok ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1325, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1274, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1034, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1448, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 94, in install_ngrok
    download_path = _download_file(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 215, in _download_file
    response = urlopen(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Files\School\Linkdemic\Linkdemic\try.py", line 3, in <module>
    phttp_tunnel = ngrok.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 251, in connect
    api_url = get_ngrok_process(pyngrok_config).api_url
  File "C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 160, in get_ngrok_process
    install_ngrok(pyngrok_config)
  File "C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 98, in install_ngrok
    installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path)
  File "C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 98, in install_ngrok
    raise PyngrokNgrokInstallError("An error occurred while downloading ngrok from {}: {}".format(url, e))
pyngrok.exception.PyngrokNgrokInstallError: An error occurred while downloading ngrok from https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

It works on my colleague's computer but not on mine. I'm not sure what the error is

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall on your computer? Shouldn't be an issue with `ngrok` or Twilio, something about your computer is blocking connectivity to https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip—can you access it from a browser?

Answer (score 5):

This can present itself in Python when you're behind certain proxies or VPNs. However, you can easily workaround this, because `install_ngrok()` takes `kwargs` that are passed down to `urlopen`, as documented [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/develop/api.html#pyngrok.installer.install_ngrok).

There are [a myriad of ways to resolve this](https://www.google.com/search?q=urllib.error.URLError%3A+%3Curlopen+error+%5BSSL%3A+CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED%5D+certificate+verify+failed%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate+(_ssl.c%3A1123)%3E&oq=urllib.error.URLError%3A+%3Curlopen+error+%5BSSL%3A+CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED%5D+certificate+verify+failed%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate+(_ssl.c%3A1123)%3E&aqs=chrome..69i57.259j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), since it's not specific to any one Python package, but if bypassing SSL verification is an acceptable security risk to your application, [here's one example for doing this in `pyngrok`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875298/python-3-urllib-with-self-signed-certificates) (also highlighted in [this issue](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok/issues/93)):

```py
import ssl
from pyngrok import ngrok, conf, installer

pyngrok_config = conf.get_default()

if not os.path.exists(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path):
    myssl = ssl.create_default_context();
    myssl.check_hostname=False
    myssl.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
    installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path, context=context)

public_url = ngrok.connect(5000).public_url
```

Answer (score 3):

You Should change:installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path, context=context) as installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path, context=myssl)

Answer (score 0):

I was on mac and got the same issue. These below steps worked for me.

Install or Update SSL Certificate.

```
/Applications/Python\ [version]/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Replace [version] with your version of Python (e.g. 3.11)

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Next, sign up with your ngrok account [ngrok's signup page](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/signup). Get the auth token [ngrok dashboard](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken). And Install it

```
./ngrok authtoken [your-authtoken]
```

Try running your program again. Hope it works.