# I Cant Use Pyngrok(certificate verify failed: certificate has expired)

Tags: python, pyngrok

I can't Use Pyngrok

Every time I run a script with the module pyngrok it displays the error:

```
Downloading ngrok ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 94, in install_ngrok
    download_path = _download_file(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 215, in _download_file
    response = urlopen(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\server1.py", line 12, in <module>
    public_url = ngrok.connect(port, "tcp", options={"remote_addr": "{}:{}".format(host, port)})
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 251, in connect
    api_url = get_ngrok_process(pyngrok_config).api_url
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 160, in get_ngrok_process
    install_ngrok(pyngrok_config)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 98, in install_ngrok
    installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 98, in install_ngrok
    raise PyngrokNgrokInstallError("An error occurred while downloading ngrok from {}: {}".format(url, e))
pyngrok.exception.PyngrokNgrokInstallError: An error occurred while downloading ngrok from https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)>
```

Please, Help!

OS: Windows11 Home Single Language
Cpu: Intel i5
python version:3.10.2(I Tried it on 3.9.7 too)

I even tried updating python and my os but it won't work!

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twilio Ngrok Automating Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416222/twilio-ngrok-automating-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Currently having the same issue, one way is to use pyopenssl

```
import requests
import json
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

url = 'https://example.com'
data = {'key': 'value'}
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
response = session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```

but I wouldn't recommend because you're not using ssl auth