# Pyngrok: SSL certificate verify failed while downloading ngrok

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyngrok

I want to tunnel my FastAPI server, so I installed pyngrok using poetry and created/activated virtual env.

Here is my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
fastapi = "^0.100.1"
uvicorn = "^0.23.2"
pyngrok = "^6.0.0"
httpx = "^0.24.1"
```

Then in virtual env I run command: `ngrok http 9000` and get such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 117, in install_ngrok
    download_path = _download_file(url, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 261, in _download_file
    response = urlopen(url, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Scripts\ngrok.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 527, in main
    run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 513, in run
    install_ngrok(pyngrok_config)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyngrok\ngrok.py", line 100, in install_ngrok
    installer.install_ngrok(pyngrok_config.ngrok_path, pyngrok_config.ngrok_version)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\fast-api-telegram-bot-a-NRO46l-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyngrok\installer.py", line 121, in install_ngrok
    raise PyngrokNgrokInstallError("An error occurred while downloading ngrok from {}: {}".format(url, e))
pyngrok.exception.PyngrokNgrokInstallError: An error occurred while downloading ngrok from https://bin.equinox.io/c/bNyj1mQVY4c/ngrok-v3-stable-windows-amd64.zip: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)>
```

I tried to open link https://bin.equinox.io/c/bNyj1mQVY4c/ngrok-v3-stable-windows-amd64.zip from traceback in browser and it dowloaded zip, I can open it and run ngrok.exe but that didn't help. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL Problem with Installing \`ngrok\` through \`pyngrok\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416222/ssl-problem-with-installing-ngrok-through-pyngrok)

Answer (score 1):

Just download `ngrok.exe` from official [website](https://ngrok.com/download), place it in your application directory and run command `ngrok http 9000`.